# Pass props to all instances of same component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my React app I am conditionally rendering views depending on which button is clicked in my menu component by passing the a `changeView` method as props from the parent to the menu. The current view is stored as state in the parent component.

I also want to use this same `changeView` method to control a button in each conditionally rendered view to go back to the menu on click.

I am currently achieving this as so:

```
render() {
  let view;
  switch(this.state.view) {
    case 0:
      view = (<Menu changeView={this.changeView} />);
      break;
    case 1:
      view = (<View changeView={this.changeView}>Test 1</View>);
      break;
    case 2:
      view = (<View changeView={this.changeView}>Test 2</View>);
      break;
    default:
      view = (<View changeView={this.changeView}>An error has ocurred!</View>);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {view}
    </div>
  );
}
```

As you can see I am having to pass the `changeView` method individually to each instance of the `View` component. Is there any way to set up the `View` component so that every instance is passed the `changeView` prop without me having to explicitly declare it each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your switch to just change copy and component if needed instead.

```
render() {
  let copy = "";
  let Component = View;

  switch (this.state.view) {
    case 0:
      Component = Menu;
      break;
    case 1:
      copy = "Test 1";
      break;
    case 2:
      copy = "Test 2";
      break;
    default:
      copy = "An error has ocurred!";
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Component changeView={this.changeView}>{copy}</Component>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try moving the switch statement inside the View component

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.state.view === 0 && <Menu changeView={this.changeView} />}
      {this.state.view > 0 && <View changeView={this.changeView}>
      {() => {
        switch (this.state.view) {
          case 1:
            return 'Test 1';
          case 2:
            return 'Test 2';
          default:
            return 'An error has ocurred!';
        }
      }}
      </View>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: for case 0 component is `Menu` not `View`

Comment: @dotconnor Thanks for the help. I think Tholle's answer is more elegant though.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is the changing text inside the view. Move the text to an array outside of the component, and select the text by the view index or fallback to the error:

```
const text = ['', 'Test 1', 'Test 2'];

class Demo extends React.Component {
  state = {
    view: 1
  }

  render() {  
    const { view } = this.state;
    const text = text[view] || 'An error has ocurred!';

    return (
      <div>
        {view === 0 ?
          <Menu changeView={this.changeView} />
          :
          <View changeView={this.changeView}>{text}</View>
        }             
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function to do that for you,

```
getView(Component, children){
    return <Component changeView = {this.changeView}>{children}</Component>
}

render() {
  let view;
  switch(this.state.view) {
    case 0:
      view = getView(Menu)
      break;
    case 1:
      view = getView(View,'Test 1')
      break;
    case 2:
      view = getView(View,'Test 2')
      break;
    default:
      view = getView(View,'An error has ocurred!');
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {view}
    </div>
  );
}
```